# How to use a variable from register in command mode?

Tags: vimscript, macro

I have a list of cities

```
London
Madrid
Paris
Brasil
```

I want to write a macro, that will add a `ul` tag and wrap each city in to an `li`.

I think, i need to create a variable like:

```
let i = 4
```

Than to write macro a(also have macros b, that will wrap each line into li)

```
qa(call var i)Vc<ul>j</ul>kp(call var i)@b
```

Comment: It seems like what you really want is the ability to use a variable as a count for commands like `V` and `@b`?

Comment: Yes, you are write, but how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the title question, but with https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround, I would do (type literally; angle brackets here are *not* key notation)

```
ysip<ul>Vitoj:normal yss<li>
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I will check a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you think you need a variable, here.

Assuming the first macro, stored into register `b`, looks something like:

```
:let @b = "^C<li>^R"</li>"
```

Then the second macro, stored in register `a`, could look like this:

```
:let @a = "c<ul>^M</ul>^[P:.,']norm @b^M"
```

with `^M` being produced with `<C-v><CR>`, `^R` produced with `<C-v><C-r>`, and `^[` produced with `<C-v><Esc>`.

This should let you visually select the lines, say with `vip`, and do `@a`:

[image: ul]

`@b` does the following:

1. move the cursor to the first printable character of the line with `^`,
2. change the rest of the line with `C`,
3. insert `<li>`,
4. insert the content of the unnamed register with `<C-r>"`,
5. insert `</li>`.

`@a` does the following:

1. change the currently selected text with `c`,
2. insert `<ul>`, followed by a carriage return, followed by `</ul>`,
3. leaves insert mode with `<Esc>`,
4. put the lines cut at step 1 above the current line with `P`,
5. execute `@b` on the lines we just changed with `:.,']norm @b<CR>`.

`:help ']` is the last line of the last change. Since the last change left you on its first line, you can create a range that covers all the lines in the last change and execute the desired macro on all those lines without having to count them.